# error in date time format while deployment

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a procedures gets me count of duplicated records and put it text box through SQL data source "SQL data source fill it`s parameters from the selected record from another gridview
everything works fine on visual studio without errors but, when I deploy it, it gives me the below error:

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

SP

```
USE [ZainJTA]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Dupplicated_Ticket]    Script Date: 01/10/2016 23:08:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Dupplicated_Ticket]
(
       @Justification_Cisco int
      ,@Justification_Date_Of_Case datetime
      ,@Justification_Justification varchar(60))

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


SELECT [Justification_Cisco] AS Cisco
, [Justification_Date_Of_Case] AS DateOfCase
, [Justification_Justification] AS Justification
, Count([Justification_Cisco]) AS NumberOfDups

FROM dbo.TBL_Justification
GROUP BY 
 Justification_Cisco
, [Justification_Date_Of_Case]
, Justification_Justification
HAVING ([Justification_Cisco]=@Justification_Cisco
AND [Justification_Date_Of_Case]=@Justification_Date_Of_Case
AND [Justification_Justification]=@Justification_Justification
AND Count([Justification_Cisco])>1
AND Count([Justification_Justification])>1)

END
```

SQL Data sorce

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Duplicated" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ZainJTAConnectionString_96 %>" SelectCommand="SP_Dupplicated_Ticket" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0000" Name="Justification_Cisco" SessionField="SelectedGridCisco" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="2009-07-22" Name="Justification_Date_Of_Case" SessionField="SelectedGridDateOfCase" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0000" Name="Justification_Justification" SessionField="SelectedGridJustification" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

assigning the parameters

```
 protected void ValidatorGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Session["SelectedGridID"] = ValidatorGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
     Session["SelectedGridCisco"] = ValidatorGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text.Trim();
     Session["SelectedGridDateOfCase"] = ValidatorGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text.Trim();
     Session["SelectedGridJustification"] = ValidatorGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.Trim();
     Response.Redirect("Validator_Details.aspx");

 }
```

get the dupplicated count through SQL data source

```
Int32 NumOfDup;
                DataView dvSql = (DataView)SqlDataSource_Duplicated.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
                foreach (DataRowView drvSql in dvSql)
                {
                    NumOfDup=System.Convert.ToInt32(drvSql["NumberOfDups"].ToString());
                    if (NumOfDup >= 2)
                    {
                        Label_Dupplicate.Text = "There are " + NumOfDup.ToString() + " Dupplicated Tickets";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label_Dupplicate.Text = "";
                    }

                }
```

is there any other easy way or what shall i do to get rid of date time error

Answer (score 0):

I think, the error might occur here:

```
Session["SelectedGridDateOfCase"] = ValidatorGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text.Trim();
```

If the text someone inputted into a grid's cell is not parseable as a date (or is empty), you'll get a conversion issue...

I'd suggest to try something like

```
var d DateTime;
if(DateTime.TryParse(ValidatorGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text.Trim(), out d))
    Session["SelectedGridDateOfCase"] = d;
else
    //assign default or handle error (user message, what ever...)
```

Comment: thanks , i found the problem in datetime format and i solved it :)